# how to count the number of event on one data.frame based on time period on another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two dataframes, one with `ID` , `DATE`, and the name of the `drug` . Another has `ID` and date of event `date.event`.

1. expected column `prev_drug` :
   how can I count the number of the different drug prior the current date ? for example, for ID=1 , prev_drug for row 4 is 2 , because it has two drugs ( A ,B) different from drug C prior the the DATE of row 4.

2.expected column `event.30d.prior` :
 for each `ID` and each `DATE` in the first data frame, how many events happened during the 30days  prior to the `DATE` ? eg. for row 2, the event for `id=1` happened at `1/20/2001` , falls in to the 30 days prior to `2/1/2001` period.

```
ID  DATE        DRUG    prev_drug   event.30d.prior     
1   1/1/2001    A       0           0       
1   2/1/2001    A       0           1       
1   3/15/2001   B       1           0       
1   4/20/2001   C       2           1           
1   5/29/2001   A       2           0           
1   5/2/2001    B       2           0           
2   3/2/2001    A       0           1           
2   3/23/2001   C       1           1           
2   4/4/2001    D       2           0           
2   5/5/2001    B       3           0   


ID  date.event
1   1/20/2001
1   4/11/2001
2   3/1/2001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with base R with some dplyr methods used.  This is not the cleanest and best solution but it should solve your problem.

```
df<-structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
DATE = structure(c(11323, 11354, 11396, 11432, 11471, 11444, 
11383, 11404, 11416, 11447), class = "Date"), DRUG = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
#Note DATE was converted to a Date object with the following line
#df$DATE<-as.Date(df$DATE, "%m/%d/%Y")

date.event<-read.table(header=TRUE, text="ID  date.event
1   1/20/2001
1   4/11/2001
2   3/1/2001")
date.event$date.event<-as.Date(date.event$date.event, "%m/%d/%Y")

library(dplyr)
#calculate the prev_drup by counting the number of unique drugs
df<-df %>% group_by(ID)  %>%  mutate(prev_drug= (cumsum(!duplicated(DRUG)))-1)


#loop through each row after spitting and filtering by ID
event.30d.prior<-sapply(1:nrow(df),  function(i){
       events<-date.event[date.event$ID==df$ID[i], "date.event"]
       sum(between(events, df$DATE[i]-30, df$DATE[i]))
})

finalanswer<-cbind(df, event.30d.prior=unlist(event.30d.prior))
```

Comment: Thank you ! I finally figured it out with a similar solution !